# Terminating app due to uncaught exception [UIImageView _isResizable]

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3, xcode8

I'm getting an exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe01fd0d470'

I just assigned an image to the `imageView` inside a custom cell using storyboard.

The code is clean. It doesn't have any warnings or errors.

Comment: Either the error in your title or your body is manually retyped because they reference different errors. Note that there isn't any reference to arrays, but you are calling `_isResizable` on an imageView instead of an actual image.

Comment: I've tried to edit and simplify your question. Please re-edit if you think something important was deleted

Comment: @budidino thank you it looks better now.

Answer (score 7):

Two reason of this error.

1. If you want to assign image write.

   `cell.image=[UIImage imagenamed:@"Name of your image "];`
2. and another reason of this error is you can cut the link of `imageView` to the outlet.

   Again make a new outlet and then check now `imageView` is working.

   **i think this will help u.**

Answer (score 2):

there may be **two or more** outlet references to one `imageView` which makes ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Please see once the name of image in swift file and StroryBoard. Compare them they must be same.
Also check the identifier of Cell.